# mysql date range query for particular date format (MMM-YY)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date column in mysql db but the dates are formatted like so:

- Jan-16
- Feb-16
- Mar-16

Is it possible to query a date range using this date format ?

For example:

```
$query = "SELECT `Total` FROM agent WHERE date >= 'Jan-16' AND date < Apr-16";
```

If this is not valid, what is the recommended way to move forward? will i have to update the date format in the db ?

Comment: if you're early in your project; yes, you should use a DATE or DATETIME type. It will make querying a lot easier

Comment: You'd be better using a `DATE` type column, or at very least a format like `YYYYMM` that sorts numerically and/or lexicographically in the same order as the months.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(date,'%M-%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Jan-16
> - Feb-16
> - Mar-16

If this column is `char` or `varchar` or other string type, and you just compare these to your parameter, it will not give what you want cause this only compare them with a character's ASCII code. You should use function `str_to_date` to format them, then you can get result in a date interval.

Like this;)

```
$query = "SELECT `Total` FROM agent
WHERE str_to_date(date, '%M-%y') >= str_to_date('Jan-16', '%M-%y')
AND str_to_date(date, '%M-%y') < str_to_date('Apr-16', '%M-%y');
```

and if your parameter is date, just use it. Also you can update your column to date, it will be a better solution.

Comment: I updated my date values to YYYY-MM-DD and column datatype to DATE and within the phpmyadmin console if i run the following query it returns the results properly but if i run the same query from php it only returns data for the first date -- any ideas?? $query = "SELECT `Answered` FROM `firstname_lastname` WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-01'";

Comment: @user3436467 Did you use `mysql_query` and fetch its result by loop in PHP?

Comment: i am using this:
`$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());`
`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: i tried using the while loop but i get an error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given..`

Comment: okay, found the problem.. my while loop was missing an 'i' for mysql_fetch_assoc -- `mysqli_fetch_assoc` works. thank you!